# How to play/record sound from Debian chroot?

Tags: audio, linux

There's big file with ext2 with ARM Debian where I can chroot to.

There's functional mplayer (I can `-ao pcm` or `-vo yuv4mpegpipe`) there.

How to record/play sound (or video) from this Debian? Is there things that emulate ALSA/OSS/Whatever to use usual linux programs and android ones side by side? May be there's pulseaudio server for android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to make it sound by writing to /dev/msm_pcm_out:

```
mplayer something.mp3 -ao pcm:file=/dev/msm_pcm_out
```

Sound is choppy and it looks hacky in general.

Video output is something like `-vo fbdev:/dev/graphics/fb0`.

Answer (score 1):

Not all Androids may have a PCM output device in `/dev`, as Vi0's answer requires.

A more general solution is to setup Pulse to [stream system audio to a TCP port](https://superuser.com/a/750324/453074) on your device. Then you can use [Simple Protocol Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kaytat.simpleprotocolplayer) or [PulseDroid](https://github.com/dront78/PulseDroid/tree/master/bin) in your Android environment to play the stream.

To eliminate chop/lag in VLC, MPlayer, and Audacity, it was necessary for me to choose ALSA as the output device and Pulse as the mixer (in these programs' options).

**Steps I used on my Amazon Fire 7" 2015 / CM12 / Debian Wheezy chroot:**

1. Install pulseaudio in the chroot: `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio`.
2. As suggested by [a comment on meefik's github](https://github.com/meefik/linuxdeploy/issues/223#issuecomment-114639940), I removed the line `load-module module-console-kit` from the file `/etc/pulse/default.pa`.
3. Run `pactl list | grep 'Name\|Description'` and identify a module that monitors system audio. I successfully used 'Dummy Output Monitor' named `auto_null.monitor`.
4. Write a corresponding shell script `pashare` as follows (credit to [AlexAndersan on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/750324/453074)):

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
    start)
        $0 stop
        pulseaudio --start
        pactl load-module module-simple-protocol-tcp rate=44100 format=s16le channels=2 source=auto_null.monitor record=true port=8000
        ;;
    stop)
        killall pulseaudio
        pactl unload-module `pactl list | grep tcp -B1 | grep M | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'`
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 start|stop" >&2
        ;;
esac
```

Make sure the `rate` and `port` arguments match your settings in Simple Protocol Player (on the Android side). PulseDroid demands `rate=48000`, which means higher throughput, and could possibly introduce chop/lag.

I added the `pulseaudio --start` and `killall` lines because pulse would not start automatically in my chroot.

5. Make the script executable and run it:

```
chmod 755 pashare
sudo mv pashare /usr/local/bin/
pashare start
```

6. Configure your chroot media players to output to ALSA, with Pulse mixer. I had to set this manually, to eliminate choppy audio:

   - **VLC**: In Tools->Preferences->Audio, set `Output module: ALSA audio output`, and `Device: Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server`.
   - **GNOME MPlayer**: In Edit->Preferences->Player, set `Audio Output: ALSA`.
7. In Android, start Simple Protocol Player or PulseDroid on IP address `127.0.0.1` (loopback) and set the other option(s) to match your `pashare` script.

Note that Android treats the app like a music player, and will kill it if another app tries to play music, or if it [decides to free up the CPU](http://www.howtogeek.com/161225/htg-explains-how-android-manages-processes/). There are probably workarounds for this.

Comment: Is it only about playing or also about recording?

Comment: @Vi0,  this also worked for [limited] recording within the chroot... just select ALSA in Audacity's input pop-up. It'll record whatever's playing through alsa.

Comment: I had trouble with e.g. Freeciv using this answer, because it uses SDL for audio which seems to auto-select the pulse driver (not alsa), and there's no way to configure that w/o recompiling.....